# Subdomains from folders on Apache

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, rewrite, wildcard-subdomain

I have a website on localhost, mapped in HOSTS as:

```
127.0.0.1 www.yorkshiretestingwebsite.com

127.0.0.1 yorkshiretestingwebsite.com
```

However, the folder (C:/www/vhosts/yorkshiretestingwebsite.com) has some sub-folders in it, namely:

leeds

hull

sheffield

and rather than typing in

http://www.yorkshiretestingwebsite.com/leeds

I would like to try and have the URL as:

http://leeds.yorkshiretestingwebsite.com

I've had a look for how to do this on Google, but am not quite sure how to do this.

I tried the advice here - https://serverfault.com/questions/235311/automatic-subdomain-creation-in-htaccess-on-apache - and it ***did*** work (good if I only have a few folders) but what if I have multiple ones? I don't want to keep adding them to it, so I've been trying to find a solution.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to create a new VirtualHost which will serve up the subdomains dynamically based on the directory tree:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wildcard.yorkshiretestingwebsite.com
    ServerAlias *.yorkshiretestingwebsite.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot "C:/www/vhosts/yorkshiretestingwebsite.com/%1"
    ... (logging, permissions, etc) ...
</VirtualHost>
```

The `%1` uses the first block of the name, so `leeds.yorkshiretestingwebsite.com` will point to `C:/www/vhosts/yorkshiretestingwebsite.com/leeds/`

More info on the `VirtualDocumentRoot` directive can be found [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html).