# Apache2 Automatic Subdomains

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost, apache-2.2

I want apache to automatically recognize subdomains based on the filename that I have placed in /var/www/subdomains/

I'm a complete apache noob.

P.S. I'm using Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: I think you need to explain what you want a bit more. I'm guessing from the question you mean you have a domain example.com and you want site1.example.com to map to /var/www/subdomains/site1/, site2.example.com to /var/www/subdomains/site2/ etc. Is that correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subdomains from folders on Apache](http://serverfault.com/questions/246652/subdomains-from-folders-on-apache)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done if you follow the instructions for [Simple dynamic virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/mass.html#simple) in the Apache documentation.

Follow a standard convention for your VirtualHosts, like `/var/www/www.subdomain.org/docroot/` and `/var/www/www.subdomain.org/cgi-bin`, and then add something like the following to your HTTP configuration.

Note how the paths below use `%0`. This will be populated by the server name which is used in the contents of the `Host:` header in the HTTP request. You must use `UseCanonicalName Off` for this to work. Also note that if a visitors goes to 'www.example.com' 'example.com', the 'Host: ' is different, therefore '%0' is different, so you'll need symlinks or another method to tell Apache that `/var/www/www.example.com/` and `/var/www/example.com/` are the same thing.

```
# get the server name from the Host: header
UseCanonicalName Off

# this log format can be split per-virtual-host based on the first field
LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
CustomLog logs/access_log vcommon

# include the server name in the filenames used to satisfy requests
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0/docs
VirtualScriptAlias  /var/www/%0/cgi-bin
```

Comment: Where do I include this? Again, new to server stuff...is it httpd.conf or apache2.conf or a .htaccess file?

Comment: @Kevin : For testing, put this in httpd.conf. Later on, you can find a more suitable location for this under the conf.d/ directory. I don't have a working Ubuntu box in front of me at the moment, but if you grep for `%0` under `/etc/apache2/*/*`, you might find some great examples for this.

Comment: When I try to restart apache I get `Invalid command 'VirtualDocumentRoot', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`.  Do I need to add a module?

Comment: I did `sudo a2enmod vhost_ailis` and restart worked!

Comment: Can I do something like `subdomain.20.34.56.67`? or must it be my actual named URL?

Comment: @Kevin There are variables available besides just '%0', and you can use that to do some creative things like '$hostname-$ipaddress'. However, I can't find a list of the variables just now.

Comment: I'd be interested in any updates--this stuff is still outside my scope of knowledge!

Comment: This is working very well for domains `example.com`, but if I want a subdomain `something.example.com` I'm having trouble.  Are there any problems that could be caused by this?

Comment: Does `/var/www/something.example.com/` exist?

Comment: Indeed it does...

Comment: Here's what I've discovered thus far: I can manually add virtualhosts to my httpd.conf and it works fine.  It isn't recgonizing anything else, though--it was recgonicing domain1.com from my `sites-available` folder that I had previously set up. I'm making headway, though!  Thanks!